# mysql counting records in a single table, help needed

Tags: mysql, sql

Simple table `object` with only two columns: `id` and `cdate` (date created). I need and sql query which would additionally show third column: **number of objects created before** each object. Simple counting is not an option - I need an explicit date comparison in the query.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean: number of objects created before each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.cdate, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yTable AS t2 WHERE t1.cdate > t2.date)  AS createdbefore
FROM yTable AS t1
```

Should suck performance-wise, as it has to count that for every row obviously. Doing this in your frontend would be better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  id,
  cdate,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(*)
   FROM
     object AS t2
   WHERE
     t2.cdate < t1.cdate)
FROM
  object AS t1
```